# Not able to get two if statements and an else statement to execute

Tags: python, if-statement

So currently I am trying to make a personal buddy program. I want it to be two if statements and one else. The two if statements have different word triggers, so that's why there is two. The problem arises when I want to make an else statement, so if the certain word triggers weren't typed, it would still say something. Here is the code

```
sport = input("What sports do you play?\n")
if sport in ['soccer','baseball','dance','basketball','golf','skiing','surfing']:
    print(sport, "sounds fun")
if sport in ['none','not at the moment','nope','none atm','natm']:
    print("Im not really into sports either")
else:
    print(sport, "is a sport?")
```

You can see the else statement should respond with "Thumbwrestling is a sport?". Instead if I say a sport listed it will trigger "Baseball sounds fun" "Baseball is a sport?" I don't want it to trigger both. Am I doing something wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

```
sport = input("What sports do you play?\n")
if sport in ['soccer','baseball','dance','basketball','golf','skiing','surfing']:
    print(sport, "sounds fun")
elif sport in ['none','not at the moment','nope','none atm','natm']:
    print("Im not really into sports either")
else:
    print(sport, "is a sport?")
```

Notice the `elif` instead of the second `if`. This stands for `else if` meaning that in the chain of statements, only one will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `if-elif-else` statement to distinguish more than two cases, instead of the conditional statement `if-else`:

```
if sport in ['soccer','baseball','dance','basketball','golf','skiing','surfing']:
    print(sport, "sounds fun")
elif sport in ['none','not at the moment','nope','none atm','natm']:
    print("I'm not really into sports either")
else:
    print(sport, "is a sport?")
```

If your going to add another case, besides the one I improved in your code, just stick to the pattern of the syntax of the `if-elif-else` statement:

```
if expression1:
   statement(s)
elif expression2:
   statement(s)
elif expression3: #You can add another line of elif if you add another case, here it is labeled expression3.
   statement(s)
else:
   statement(s)
```